# IBM Integration Bus - Business Monitor

Tags: ibm-bpm, ibm-integration-bus

Can someone explain how the IIB (Integration Bus) and the Business Monitor are connected together?

I've defined monitoring events in my flow.
I then exported the monitoring information to create a model.
Used the model to create an EAR file which I installed in BM as a model.
Used the `mqsichangeflowmonitoring` command to activate monitoring on all flows.
But when I run my flow, nothing happens, no events are recorded, nothing shows up in business space.

So I think some crucial link between the 2 systems is missing but I can't figure out what it is.
I've already read about creating topics or so, but this information wasn't clear to me.

If someone could shed some light on this it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

1. you must configure the `database` for monitoring first.
2. Create `DataCaptureStore` and `DataCaptureSource`.
3. Define the topic and subscription object.
4. Define the `backout queue`.
5. for each terminal you like to record event define the data you want to export with the event.

for more details about steps above :

take this Link it helps : [View Monitoring events Via IBM Integration Bus Web UI](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/546b8634-f33d-4ed5-834e-e7411faffc7a/entry/view_monitoring_events_via_ibm_integration_bus_web_ui?lang=en)

Comment: I disagree. The facts may be true, but Abu taha is not answering the question. The question is about how to connect IIB and IBM Business Monitor. For that task you do not need a Record/Replay database at all.

Answer (score 0):

You may have already done this, but you did not mention it...
You need to install a message-driven bean ( MDB ) which subscribes to the topic and forwards the IIB events to Business Montitor as CBEs. See http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSMKHH_9.0.0/com.ibm.etools.mft.doc/ac60392_.htm